# Facebook "likes" redirects users to app apge and not to facebook

Tags: facebook, namespaces, facebook-like

I have a Wordpress blog with Facebook like buttons.
When someone "likes" a post on my WP blog, it writes on his wall something like:
**[username] likes an article on [app name]**
and than there's a link to the post.
The problem is, that if you click the [app name] it redirects to the app page inside Facebook which is bad since there is no real app. it's just the blog inside Facebook ugly ugly iframe.

How can I make the [app name] to direct clicks to the website and not to Facebook app page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
or a plugin? I've been using the like-btn generated at that page with Facebook before without experiencing the problems you've described.

Comment: Yes, although lately I've implemented Facebook WP official plugin, without changing current buttons.

Comment: BTW, only after i've installed Facebook WP official plugin, the app name appear, which is nice but it redirects to a wrong page...

Comment: Then you'll have to provide a jsfiddle of the code used to present the WP Plugin. My guess is that the plugin asked you to enter your application url somewhere and is using that as the url-ref for the like-link, which of course will give you the situation you describe. If I create a JS Fiddle with the code provided from FB, I dont experience your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncb6F/. With that said: the problem is with your plugin and the code will be required as i mentioned above.